# bash script to create a menu from a random list of files

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, menu

I have a python script which creates a certain amount of files (could be different per environment).
from that script i want to create a bash script that will create a menu from that list of files.

I am using the following :

```
#!/bin/bash
files=$(ls -lh /home/admin/output | grep txt | awk '{print $9}' | sed -n '1!p')
PS3="Pick an Object:"
select devnum in $files; do
     line=$REPLY
     break
done
```

it works , however i don't know how to assign an action for each option.

for example :

```
1) object1
2) object2
```

how do i assign an action to each command?
basically i want to execute # vi {file name from menu} for each of the menu options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stored the result in `$devnum`, so just run

```
vi "$devnum"
```

below `done`.

BTW, are you sure `devnum` is the correct variable name?

Comment: Thanks for the update. Basically I took it from a different thread here. My idea is to create a menu from a list of random files (that are created by a different program) and then when selecting wax option - to be able to enter each file separately (via #vi )